# NSCFData, AXUIElement Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, core-foundation

I'm running Instruments and it is reporting 3 leaks of object-types _NSCFData, AXUIElement, and Malloc, and pointing to the following function. I'm doing some bridging as the CF objects are not managed. I can't seem to figure out how or why this function is leaking.

```
- (NSArray *)subelementsFromElement:(AXUIElementRef)element forAttribute:(NSString *)attribute {
    CFArrayRef subElementsCFArrayRef;
    NSArray *subElements=nil;
    CFIndex count=0;
    AXError result;

    result=AXUIElementGetAttributeValueCount(element, (__bridge CFStringRef)attribute, &count);
    if(result!=kAXErrorSuccess) return nil;
    result=AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(element, (__bridge CFStringRef)attribute, 0, count, &subElementsCFArrayRef);
    if(result!=kAXErrorSuccess) return nil;

    subElements=(__bridge NSArray*)subElementsCFArrayRef;

    return subElements;
}
```

If this method doing everything properly?

Answer (score 0):

`subElementsCFArrayRef` is leaking.

[Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)

[Managing Toll-Free Bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1)